# What are the Disadvantages/problems when using IceFaces with Spring framework?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, icefaces

i intend to use IceFaces with spring framework
and i was wondering about the disadvantages/problems of this approach, if there's any ?
please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring has had decent support for JSF based applications for some time (I used it in a JSF 1.1 application without issue) so you shouldn't have any complications introduced into your application by using Spring.